# Why am I getting Error: Configuration property “jwtPrivateKey” is not defined?

Tags: node.js, config

I keep getting this error message when I run my index.js file via NodeJS terminal. My editor is VS Code. I am on Windows.

I loaded npm config module into my index.js file. I created a custom-environment-variables.json. I set my password, vidlyPrivateKey, in my Node Terminal. I don't know why this is happening. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my index.js code:

```
const config = require('config');
try {
    const myKey = config.get("jwtPrivateKey");
    debug(myKey);
} catch (error) {
    debug(error, "FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey is not defined.");
   return process.exit(1);
}
```

custom-environment-variables.json:

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "vidlyPrivateKey"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the naming of the file, it should be inside a `config` folder and be name as `default.json` , `config/default.json`

[image]

These are the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/config.

Comment: I have a config folder. I tried putting the property/value in the default.json file. I still get the same error message.